# Combining data and calculating standard deviation statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

**The problem** (translated from Swedish, the correct mathematical terms might not be written but I will do my best):

"
*For two sets of data $x_1,...,x_5$ and $y_1,...,y_9$ pre-calculated values are:*

$\bar x=12.2 $ *and* $s_x=2.1$

$\bar y=15.8$ *and* $s_y=2.9$

*(where $s_x$ and $s_y$ is the standard deviation for the x and y data)*

*You now want to combine the data to one larger data $z_1,..., z_{14}$*

*Calculate the mean value and standard deviation for the new combined data.*
"

**What I have come up with**

For the mean value I calculate it like this:

$\frac{12.2\times5+15.8\times9}{9+5}=14.51=\bar z$

This is correct according to the book, however, I do not know how to calculate the standard deviation, the correct answer is $s_z=13.2$

Comment: Some formulas need to know $\sum x^2$ but we only know $\sum x$. Is there any way to calculate  $\sum x^2$?